# Getting batch file to auto rename input file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a batch file to process videos and rename the output file automatically.

I've got this so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
d:\audio\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -vcodec copy -acodec libvo_aacenc -af volume=3.0 "%~1"
pause
```

The last "%~1" will overwrite the initial file. What I'd like is that they append something to the back of the file, for example:

filename.avi will return filename1.avi

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Why the tilde in %~1? Shouldn't that just be %1? Anyway just try appending a 1 and make it %11. The % placeholder only goes up to 9, so two digits are not interpreted as a number > 10

Comment: Cos I'm drag-n-dropping a file onto the BAT and my video files have long path names with spaces in it.

I tried added 1 behind, but ffmpeg does not recognize .avi1 as a file type and will break. Optimally I would like to concatenate the last 4 chars, edit the filename, append the last 4 chars back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appends random number to output file name.

```
set output=%~dpn1%random%%~x1
d:\audio\ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -vcodec copy -acodec libvo_aacenc -af volume=3.0 "%output%"
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks!.... now to figure out what you did there. I'd like to append a fixed wording like "fixed" to the end instead of random numbers.

Comment: And it's as simple as removing %random% and replacing it with whatever I want :) thanks again!